# Applying a custom CharTokenizer in Solr4

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solr4

I just wrote a custom `CharTokenizer`, and I want to use it in my Solr server.

In Solr3, I could just extend `TokenizerFactory` and return my `CharTokenizer` in the create method, but `TokenizerFactory` does not exist in Solr4.

So, I was noticed that I should replace `TokenizerFactory` with `TokenFilterFactory`, but in this case, I cannot return my custom `CharTokenizer`, because the parameters don't match.

I also search for some documentation, but looks like there is nothing really useful about that out there.

So, how can I make it works?

Example:

```
public class MyCustomTokenizer extends CharTokenizer {

  char anotherSpace = 24;

  public MyCustomTokenizer(Version matchVersion, Reader in) {
    super(matchVersion, in);
  }

  protected boolean isTokenChar(int c) {
    return !Character.isWhitespace(c) && isToken((char) c);
  }

  private boolean isToken(char c) {
    if (c == anotherSpace || c == ',') {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}

public class MyCustomTokenizerFactory extends TokenFilterFactory {

  public void init(Map<String, String> args) {
    super.init(args);
    assureMatchVersion();
  }

  @Override
  public TokenStream create(TokenStream input) {
      // sh*t happens here
    return new MyCustomTokenizer(luceneMatchVersion, input);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to check for implementation is looking the Source code of an existing Tokenizer in Lucene.

Example :-

[WhitespaceTokenizer](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/4.0.0-ALPHA/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/WhitespaceTokenizer.java#WhitespaceTokenizer)
[WhitespaceTokenizerFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-core/4.0.0-ALPHA/org/apache/solr/analysis/WhitespaceTokenizerFactory.java?av=h)